# Segmentation fault when deleting template array

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator, delete-operator

So i need to create an array of dynamic size containing pairs of objects and I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hey #1" << endl;

    pair<string, int> *array;

    array = new pair<string, int>[4];

    cout << "Hey #2" << endl;

    delete array;

    cout << "Hey #3" << endl;
}
```

and the output I get is

```
Hey #1
Hey #2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

which means that something goes wrong when the `delete` operator gets called?

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `array = new pair<string, int>[4];` -- What are you really trying to accomplish here?  Second, do not call your variable `array`, as there is a `std::array` class that exists in standard C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Create an array containing 4 pairs.

Comment: Since you stated you are creating an array, what form of `delete` should you be using when deleting an array?  Also `std::array<std::pair<std::string, int>, 4>` would avoid having to use `new`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For sure not the one I was using. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the operator delete []

```
delete [] array;
```

Answer (score 4):

When you allocate objects with `new`, you need to free them with `delete`; when you allocate objects with `new[]` you need to free them with `delete[]`. Change your code to:

```
delete[] array;
```

Answer (score 4):

When deleting a dynamic array use `delete[]` instead of `delete` to delete multiple dynamically allocated data. Hope this solves your problem.